# jwplayer video stretching not working

Tags: jwplayer

I am using jwplayer premium version in my project . The problem is the video is not getting stretched to any of those options (exactfit,fill) . My code is

```
            <script>
        jwplayer("mi-vdo-container").setup({
          image: "<?php echo get_post_meta ($this_postID, 'Video-image', true); ?>",
          sources: [{
            file: "<?php echo get_post_meta ($this_postID, $jw_player_sd, true); ?>"
          },{
            file: "<?php echo get_post_meta ($this_postID, $jw_player_hd, true); ?>"
          }],
          width: 640,
          height: 360,
          stretching: 'exactfit'              
        });
        </script>
```

The video is playing but the stretching option is not working .

Comment: Please give us a link to your site. My quick test on a simple embed shows that option working as expected.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: I am working on a dev localhost . SO the website is still not live . In html5 mode this can't be done . I tried it i had to use flash player to get this working